# Replace item in array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I want to change the location of the 2 and 5. Later I want to print again. How can I do?

```
<body>
  <div id="test"></div>
  <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="test();">
  <script>
    function test() {
      var arr = [2, 5];
      $("#test").append(" " + arr[0] + "," + arr[1] + "<br>");
      if (arr[0] < arr[1]) {
        arr[1] = arr[0];
        $("#test").append(" " + arr[0] + "," + arr[1] + "<br>");
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a **temp variable** for swapping:

```
function test() {
  var arr = [2, 5];
  $("#test").append(" " + arr[0] + "," + arr[1] + "<br>");
  if (arr[0] < arr[1]) {
    var t = arr[1];
    arr[1] = arr[0];
    arr[0] = t;
    $("#test").append(" " + arr[0] + "," + arr[1] + "<br>");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tidy the logic here quite simply. First of all, instead of building the string manually, use `join()`. Secondly, in your if condition, instead of reversing the order of elements one by one using their index just use the `reverse()` method. Finally, you can re-order your logic so that you get the array in the state you need before setting the `html()` of the div. With all that said, try this:

```
function test() {
    var arr = [2, 5];
    if (arr[0] < arr[1])
        arr.reverse();
    $("#test").append(arr.join(',') + "<br>");
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/t95zsrd1/)

Comment: I know some ready functions but I want to make algorithmic. Thanks for help.